# QFontMetrics give strange results for monospace font

Tags: qt, qfont, qfontmetrics

Сan someone explain to me results of this test program?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFontMetrics>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QFont font;
    font.fromString("Monospace,14");
    QFontMetrics fm(font);
    qDebug() << "W       : " << fm.width('W');
    qDebug() << "8*W     : " << 8*fm.width('W');
    qDebug() << "WWWWWWWW: " << fm.width("WWWWWWWW"); // 8*W
    return 0;
}
```

After comipiling this code with Qt5.11 I have such results:

> ```
> W       :  11
> 8*W     :  88
> WWWWWWWW:  92
> ```

Size of one character 'W' for this monospace font is 11. I expect that size of string that consists of 8 such characters should be 88. But QFontmetrics::width returns 92!

Comment: Just for info, as I was also searching for an explanation, it seems that width() is now obsolete http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf-obsolete.html#width-1

Comment: unable to repro it. I see 21,168,168 .....Windows Qt 5.12

Comment: Linux Qt 5.12: 11,88,92

Comment: Not reproducible on Qt 5.6.3 or Qt5.9.1 on Windows 7. Do you get similar results when using [`horizontalAdvance()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#horizontalAdvance) instead of `width()`?

Comment: @Mike Yes, horizontalAdvance() gives same result

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in rounding. If I use `QFontMetricsF` instead of `QFontMetrics` results are correct

```
W       :  11.4375
8*W     :  91.5
WWWWWWWW:  91.5
```

But I found another strange thing. `QFontMetricsF::maxWidth()` should returns qreal type, but in fact it always returns rounded value (11 in my example). It looks like bug in Qt.
https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTBUG/issues/QTBUG-73458?filter=allopenissues